# Formatted dateTime submits as invalid when updating

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-4

I have a dateTime column in DB in my Model I have specified it as `$dates = ['due_date'];` so that it will be a Carbon object.

I then display this in my Edit View with this code

```
{{ Form::input('datetime-local', 'due_date', 
   strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', strtotime($todolist->due_date)), 
   array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Now using this code I have managed to display the date time in the HTML5 input with type `datetime-local`. My problem is that when submitting the Form to Update the record I get an error **"Unexpected Data Found"** because it is now posting the following string

`1961-06-16T08:57:17`

My question: How do I display the dateTime field, and also have a valid dateTime when submitting the form.

Comment: Try putting this in to a Carbon instance then updating. Like so; `$input = Input::all(); $input['datetime-local'] = Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($input['datetime-local']));` Then update with inserting the array $input into the update method. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: @MattBurrow that solved it, thanks. Although you might want to put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: added it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in to a Carbon instance then updating. Like so;

```
$input = Input::all(); 
$input['datetime-local'] = Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($input['datetime-local']));
```

Then update with inserting the array `$input` into the update method.